# Populate data from one html file to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two html pages named order.html,check.html and test.js(included in both html files)
When i click on submit button in order.html,amount field value from order.html should get updated/populate into cost field of check.html.
Below is the code i am using but its not working,can someone let me know whats wrong??

**order.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="order" action="check.html" method="get">
name:<input type ="text" id="amount" name="amount">
<input type="submit" value="finish" onclick="cost()" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**check.html**

```
 <head>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="check" action="confirm.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" readonly="readonly">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**test.js**

```
function cost(){
var amount= $("#amount").val();
jQuery.load("check.html",function(){
$("#cost").html(amount);
});
}
```

Comment: Take a look at what `.load` does: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

order.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main_div">
        <form name="order" action="check.html" method="get">
            name:<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"> <input
                type="button" value="finish" id="submit_btn">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        $('#main_div').load("check.html", function() {
            $('#main_div').find("#cost").val(amount);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello,i tried the above code but when i enter data and click on finish button in order.html page it is not re-directing to check.html page at all

Comment: Yes page will not redirect because i have changed your button type "submit" to "button". Since we are getting the data of check.html through Jquery.load method, that is why i have changed the button type.

Answer (score 0):

Your order.html input type submit should be input type button.

Answer (score 0):

Change your test.js to

```
function cost(){
  var amount= $("#amount").val();
  $('body').load("check.html",function(){
    $("#cost").val(amount);
  });
}
```

And `input type="button"`